# Access scope from link function in directive AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am trying to access the data in an ng-repeat from the link or controller function of the directive. My directive code looks like this.

```
app.directive('ssLeftNavDirective', function($rootScope) {
// Runs during compile
    return {
        templateUrl: 'leftnavmenu.html',
        scope: {
            displayMode: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.tests = ['health check', 'Performance Monitor', 'Compare Test', 'API Helpdesk'];
            $scope.troubleshooting = ['Trouble Shooting 1', 'Trouble Shooting 2', 'Trouble Shooting 3'];
            $scope.help = ['Help 1', 'Help 2', 'Help 3'];
            $scope.settings = ['Settings 1', 'Settings 2', 'Settings 3'];
        },
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.menuDisplayed = true;
            $scope.tests = ['health check', 'Performance Monitor', 'Compare Test', 'API Helpdesk'];
            $scope.troubleshooting = ['Trouble Shooting 1', 'Trouble Shooting 2', 'Trouble Shooting 3'];
            $scope.help = ['Help 1', 'Help 2', 'Help 3'];
            $scope.settings = ['Settings 1', 'Settings 2', 'Settings 3'];
        }
    };
});
```

I added it both in controller and link, to test it.

And this is the directive template:

```
<div id="menudiv">
<nav id="leftnavmenu" ng-class="menuDisplayed ? 'navon' : 'navoff'">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="nav in displayMode">{{nav}}</a>
</nav>
<i class="fa hamburgermenu" aria-hidden="true"
          ng-class="menuDisplayed ? 'menuon fa-times' : 'menuoff fa-bars'"
          ng-click="menuDisplayed = !menuDisplayed">
</i>
```

In the main HTML I am adding the directive and scope value like this.

```
    <ss-left-nav-directive display-mode="tests"></ss-left-nav-directive>
```

Why isn't tests being passed from the display-mode scope? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if the `tests` array belongs to your directive, then you shouldn't need to use an isolate scope to get it. You can simply use `$scope.tests` to retrieve it. If it belongs to the parent controller, then look at @32teeth's answer below

Comment: The directive controller and the directive link function access the **isolate** *child* scope of the directive. The directive two-way `=` bound attribute accesses the *parent* scope variables. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `tests` at the wrong place . Instead of defining it in the link function or controller of the directive , It should be defined in the controller of template in which the directive is used . So for ,

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  <ss-left-nav-directive display-mode="tests"></ss-left-nav-directive>
</div>
```

In the AppController (or whichever controller `tests` binded to) ,

```
    app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.tests = ['health check', 'Performance Monitor', 'Compare Test', 'API Helpdesk'];
    });
```

And the below directive should work,

```
    app.directive('ssLeftNavDirective', function ($rootScope) {
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        templateUrl: 'leftnavmenu.html',
        scope: {
            displayMode: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.menuDisplayed = true;
        },
        link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        }
    };
});
```